# Merge Master Branch (HotFixes) into Feature Branch via REST API Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

we need to merge the master code (hotfixes commits) into feature branch via bitbucket REST API. There is an option of sync on Bitbucket cloud but via can't find any rest API for it.

Whereas the same thing it possible in GitHub check [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/).